MPI FFT Implementation Produces Incorrect Results with Multiple Ranks
I am working on an MPI implementation of the Cooley-Tukey FFT algorithm in C++. The implementation is supposed to distribute the computation of the FFT across multiple processes. It works correctly with a single rank but fails to produce the correct results when executed with two or more ranks. I believe the issue might be related to how data dependencies are handled between the FFT stages when data is split among different processes.
void cooley_tukey_fft(vector<complex<double>>& x, bool inverse) {
    int N = x.size();
    for (int i = 1, j = N / 2; i < N - 1; i++) {
        if (i < j) {
            swap(x[i], x[j]);
        }
        int k = N / 2;
        while (k <= j) {
            j -= k;
            k /= 2;
        }
        j += k;
    }
    double sign = (inverse) ? 1.0 : -1.0;
    for (int s = 1; s <= log2(N); s++) {
        int m = 1 << s;
        complex<double> omega_m = exp(complex<double>(0, sign * 2.0 * PI / m));
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k += m) {
            complex<double> omega = 1.0;
            for (int j = 0; j < m / 2; j++) {
                complex<double> t = omega * x[k + j + m / 2];
                complex<double> u = x[k + j];
                x[k + j] = u + t;
                x[k + j + m / 2] = u - t;
                omega *= omega_m;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    // Hardcoded data for all processes (replicated)
    vector<complex<double>> data = {
        {88.1033, 45.955},
        {12.194, 72.0208},
        {97.1567, 18.006},
        {51.3203, 99.5343},
        {98.0407, 57.5992},
        {70.6577, 20.4711},
        {44.7407, 84.487},
        {20.2791, 39.3583}
    };

    int count = data.size();

    // Calculate the local size for each process
    int local_n = count / size;
    vector<complex<double>> local_data(local_n);

    // Scatter the data to all processes
    MPI_Scatter(data.data(), local_n * sizeof(complex<double>), MPI_BYTE,
                local_data.data(), local_n * sizeof(complex<double>), MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // Local FFT computation
    cooley_tukey_fft(local_data, false);

    // Gather the results back to the root process
    vector<complex<double>> result;
    if (rank == 0) {
        result.resize(count);
    }
    MPI_Gather(local_data.data(), local_n * sizeof(complex<double>), MPI_BYTE,
               result.data(), local_n * sizeof(complex<double>), MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // Output the results from the root process
    if (rank == 0) {
        cout << "FFT Result:" << endl;
        for (const auto& c : result) {
            cout << c << endl;
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

